# dkim signature not present or bad format

Tags: postfix, debian-lenny, dkim

I'm going mad with dkim-filter + postfix. My message are signed but Gmail notify me errors like `"dkim=neutral(no signature)"` or `"dkim=neutral(bad format)"`

I don't know what is wrong. I've generated public and private key, and I'm using the right selector.  My dns entry looks like that:

```
default._domainkey.accessdev-mail.com.       IN TXT   "v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDaSlf0l7scGWVaOlPlPX4C8Mce
v3C7QpDBdwcJ+rw36GVlcJaJ2QU2yfh/VXr81DhmNbmBGyCH8EzK/FT42vAw7rp3
NqnEH9DFNDx7SDVql/liDKKSBWDfZu+QjhU4qPdEuL8bZ0EW3wTmAc2WNnQY7M+t
A8ryjVM7qonJLY78YwIDAQAB"
```

Comment: If accessdev-mail.com is your real domain, your DNS is in bad shape. The DNS servers according to `whois` are `SD2.ACCESS-DEV.FR` which returns no results for any queries (including SOA) about the accessdev-mail.com domain, and `SDNS2.OVH.NET` which I can't seem to get that TXT record from.

Comment: Note that if you send the e-mails out via PHP mail() this could be causing trouble as well. Unfortunately I cannot remember exactly what fixed it and the server I used it on does not exist any longer.

Answer (score 1):

first. are you using yours DNS server or some VPS? there were trables that IPS DNS servers makes yours IN TXT entry to lowercase.

second. try to remove g=*

Check yours TXT records from outside your server,some external resource

Comment: I m on a dedicated server , not VPS. my dns server is bind9 , i removed g=* but still the same problem (bad format)

Comment: look like yours provided info is right. try to recreate yours keys private and public

Comment: Can you check yours dns records from external source with dig or nslookup by txt fields?